# Choosing between a Web App Bot and a Function Bot

Tags: azure, botframework

When creating a bot in Azure Bot Service you have two hosting options according to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-overview-introduction

App Service Plan (Standard Azure web app, Web App Bot)
Consumption Plan (Azure Functions, Functions Bot)

I'm trying to understand the strengths and weaknesses of each. The billing model of a Function Bot would work best for my use case, but I seem to be finding limitations. It also seems that Microsoft's documentation is biased towards Web App Bots being the standard.

Here is what I know so far:

1. The billing model is different. App Services plans are billed more like an always running VM vs. Functions are pay-per-run.
2. App Service uses the standard ASP.NET MVC model. Functions use C# scripts
3. Visual Studio seems to have better support for debugging and publishing App Service plan bots

One thing I think is related to #2 is Global Message handling. The examples Microsoft gives for implementing a global message handler seems to require the use of global.asax.cs to register the global handler, this file isn't present in a Function Bot.

Are Web App bots the preferred option from Microsoft?

Is .NET Core better supported in either option?

Is there a way to implement global handlers in Function Bots?

Are there other specific weaknesses of Function Bots?

Is one option more "modern" than the other?

Comment: In my *opinion* one would choose for app services when one is already present, otherwise choose function because of the lower pricing. An app plan does give a predefined performance though, and has the "always on" ability. But there are to many factors to count in for an adequate answer of this (too broad) question

Comment: Good question but complicated to answer here. A few more points: Function Bot has been released long after Web App Bot (hence the gap and the difference of number of samples/information), .Net Core is the base of Bot SDK v4

Comment: There's a bit too much here for one StackOverflow question.  You might get a better response asking this on https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder  That said, I'd personally avoid building an Azure Functions bot in production until this is resolved: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/992

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, I realize some of this is subjective and dependent on your requirements. BUt thanks for sharing your opinions, I look into the v4 SDK and github repo.