# Difference between Functions Bot, Web App Bot & Bot Channels Registration in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

What's the difference?
I couldn't find specific information about all three services here or on Microsoft Azure or on Azure Bot Service...

Comment: Did you [researched SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088014/choosing-between-a-web-app-bot-and-a-function-bot) before asking this question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Function and Web App bots are essentially the same thing. The core difference is that most of the business logic for a functions bot is contained in one or more Azure functions which are c# scripts, while the business logic for a WebApp bot is contained in an WebAPI running as an App Service.
Now, a Bot Channels Regstration is an entirely different beast. This resource is what you use when you want to use the Bot Service functionality in Azure. It is the middle piece to connect your bot to the various channels that it supports. A channel is an external 'client application' such as Facebook Messenger, Twitter, twillio, web chat, etc.
This is the basics but there is plenty of information in the Bot Framework documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Registration of Web App Bot and Bot Channels is deprecated as of 9/1/2021. **Azure Bot** takes the place of both the Web App Bot resource and Bot Channels resource types.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-bot-service-bot-framework-composer/2-what-is-azure-bot-service