# Bot Framework Virtual Assistant as MS Teams Bot

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

Using the MS Virtual Assistant Template I have deployed a Bot, with LUIS , QnA maker etc, but using the methods  I have previously used, I'm unable to install a bot in teams to consume whats been deployed.... any guidance, references would be of great help surrounding bot deployment in teams with MS VA

Comment: Are you talking about for production, testing, or both?

Comment: both..

so the thing is right, when i deploy the virtual assistant with PS like you are suppsoed to it provisions everything, the only thing that is missing is App registration.

As in when you create a bot in the azure portal it auto create s the App Id and Password and registers it, the VA deplyment auto creates the App ID, and uses the PW you supply, but doesnt resister the app (you know, for greaph permissions etc?

Comment: when the VA is provisioned and you click 'manage' i get this experience, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2018/03/05/issues-with-managing-bot-registration-properties/ . now i dont know if this is related to why i cant get it working in teams but at the moment seems all i have to go on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to explicitly add the graph permissions for your Virtual Assistant app registration. There is a guide on how permissions can be added [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration#api-permissions) (`Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > Your App > API Permissions`.

I don't believe a Bot registration is what you want, my understanding as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52190623/5209435) is that a Bot Channels Registration resource is to connect your bot from outside Azure to channels supported by Azure, i.e. you have your own custom bot written in your own Framework but you want to expose it to people via the Azure Bot Service.

For both testing a bot in MS Teams and getting it into production your will need to register your bot for the MS Teams channel. You go to `Your Bot > Channels > MS Teams > Click through the prompts`. The official guide is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Once you have done the above you will be able to access your bot in MS Teams via it's ID Guid (`Microsoft App ID` - which can be found under `Your Bot > Settings`). You can search for the Microsoft App ID in the search bar of teams, then your bot should display under the People tab as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-test#talk-to-your-bot-directly-by-id). At this stage you are talking to your bot hosted in Azure but *it is still not published.*

When you are happy with your bots functionality you can look into [creating an app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-upload) for your bot - I would recommend using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio) for this, if you need to publish it to only the catalog for your tenant then a guide is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/tenant-apps-catalog-teams).

As an aside to run your bot locally but debug it in a channel of your choice (MS Teams, Web Chat etc) you can follow [this guide](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2018/04/run-your-app-in-teams-but-debug-locally-using-ngrok-heres-how/) to get remote debugging *temporarily* setup via ngrok.

Comment: Thanks the missing bit was Your Bot > Channels > MS Teams > Click through the prompts, thanks!!! I kept seeing this in the demos, but they were old demos and it didnt look like this. Thanks for that!

Comment: No problem, best of luck.